# Incoming Webhooks risks?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Any idea what's the risk exposure when somebody accidentally loses the incoming webhook url for a Microsoft Teams channel?

To my understanding, data like team members or messages  are not accessible and basically the person having the url could potentially just spam the channel but not really extract anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. There will be no such risks with the incoming webhook url. One can only push connector cards to Microsoft Teams channels. Team Members and messages are not accessible using the webhook url.

Comment: being able to send unauthenticated messages which are considered to be trustworthy by the readers, is definatly a possible vector of attac, imagine you regulary push your intranet news to a teams channel, and one day someone not nice sends you a message like "click here to register for our company x-mas party" ...

Answer (score 2):

The biggest risk is, that (unless I understand something wrong) if someone with malicious intent got that URL, he/she could send Actionable Message with form and send the contents of that form to endpoint that is beyond your control. They could e.g. disguise that form as form provided by HR and requesting some sensitive info.

This seems like a huge hole in security, and I still think/hope that I just understand it wrong.

Comment: No, that's not true. Actionable messages (outbound traffic endpoints) must be centrally registered with Microsoft. There is no way to respond to hypothetical spam actionable messages.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT thanks for the info, has this changed recently? Because at a time of writing that message I had a working POC where I was sending an actionable message from an unregistered azure function to a teams channel via Incoming Webhook (function hosted in tenant other than the o365 tenant where the Incoming Webhook was configured) and sent the information posted via the actionable message form back to that azure function. Also, at the time, noone from the Microsoft employees I asked that question gave me the answer you just did.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT do you have any links that explain this? The Incoming Webhook for Microsoft Teams has been disabled specifically in our organization but the same works fine in the outlook. I dont see any difference between Incoming Webhook for Teams and for Outlook. Is there any difference between them?